# Showing particular area in google PlacePicker

Tags: android, gmsplacepicker

I am working on an android application which requires user to select his/her location. I am using Google's PlacePikcer API to do so. It is working fine, but I want to show a particular area when I click on PlacePicker button. For example when I start the placepicker intent, it should show the map of a particular area or radius to make the search more specific.
I searched a lot but couldn't find a way. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach.

```
LatLng bottomLeft = new LatLng(**bottom left latitude** , **bottom left longitude**);
LatLng topRight = new LatLng(**top right latitude** , **top right longitude**);

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(bottomLeft ,topRight);


PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(bound);

// now use intentBuilder to build intent.
```

**bottom left latitude** and **bottom left longitude** mark the bottom left corner of the area you want to show and **top right latitude** and **top right  longitude** mark the top right corner of the area.

Comment: Thanks.. it did help a lot.

Comment: Is it also possible to add only one `LatLng` as center of the screen and let the ``PlacePicker` build up the screen? Should be possible with the `Builder` but I can't get it work...

Comment: @Cilenco : build two LatLng as `new LatLng(center - 0.005, center - 0.005)` and `new LatLng(center + 0.005, center + 0.005)` and pass them into the LatLngBounds and use it in the Builder. Thus the PlacePicker will build the screen around the **center** the you specify. Increase **0.005** to some other value to get more area around **center**. Decrease it to reduce the area around **center**.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me after I changed the order of Longitude and Latitude in the `new LatLng(...)` statement.